# How to dynamically sum fields when the names are unknow in advance?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is my setup.

```
DROP TABLE   test_table 
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    AsOfDate Date,
    DESC1 varchar(10),
    [I.A.3] varchar(10),
    [I.A.6] varchar(10),
    [U.T.1] varchar(10),
    [U.G.5] varchar(10)
);
INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,[I.A.3],[I.A.6],[U.T.1],[U.G.5])
VALUES ('9-30-2017','0063','3543.20','32532.45','4563.67','45788.89')
INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,[I.A.3],[I.A.6],[U.T.1],[U.G.5])
VALUES ('9-30-2017','0063','3589.20','35532.45','7763.67','20788.89')
INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,[I.A.3],[I.A.6],[U.T.1],[U.G.5])
VALUES ('9-30-2017','0063','5543.20','36132.45','6063.67','91788.89')
INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,[I.A.3],[I.A.6],[U.T.1],[U.G.5])
VALUES ('9-30-2017','0063','3113.20','852532.45','1263.67','56788.89')
INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,[I.A.3],[I.A.6],[U.T.1],[U.G.5])
VALUES ('9-30-2017','0063','8543.90','972532.45','3363.67','3788.89')

Select *
From test_table
```

[image]

I will have dynamic IDs coming into a query, as you can see in the image above.  I will always have 'AsOfDate' and 'DESC1' but the IDs will change over time.  Today I have four, but next week I could have five ('X.C.4', or whatever).  How can I sum the totals of IDs, by Date and Desc1, like I show in the yellow highlight, below?

[image]

Comment: What don't you look in the system catalog for the columns in the table before building the query http://geekswithblogs.net/AskPaula/archive/2008/07/31/124161.aspx

Comment: What are you calling an "ID"?   There are no columns named ID in your table or your query.

Comment: I would ask why the columns are always changing. This sounds like something is not designed very well.

Comment: Sorry, the IDs are: I.A.3, I.A.6, U.T.1, and U.G.5.  It's only this way because the data is pivoted.  The columns will change over time as new IDs are added.  I didn't come up with this design.  I just inherited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider thinking about your problem differently. I've redesigned your schema so that you don't have periodically add new columns to account for new data.

```
    DROP TABLE test_table
    GO
    CREATE TABLE test_table
    (
        AsOfDate datetime NOT NULL,
        DESC1 int NOT NULL,
        DynamicId varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        [Value] decimal(12,4) NOT NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',63,'[I.A.3]',3589.20)
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',64,'[I.A.3]',3543.20)
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',65,'[I.A.3]',5543.20)
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',66,'[I.A.3]',3113.20)
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',67,'[I.A.3]',8543.90)                                 
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',63,'[I.A.6]',32532.45)
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',64,'[I.A.6]',35532.45)
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',65,'[I.A.6]',36132.45)
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',66,'[I.A.6]',852532.45)
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',67,'[I.A.6]',972532.45)                       
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',63,'[U.T.1]',4563.67)
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',64,'[U.T.1]',7763.67)
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',65,'[U.T.1]',6063.67)
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',66,'[U.T.1]',1263.67)
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',67,'[U.T.1]',3363.67)                             
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',63,'[U.G.5]',45788.89)
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',64,'[U.G.5]',20788.89)
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',65,'[U.G.5]',91788.89)
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',66,'[U.G.5]',56788.89)
    INSERT INTO test_table (AsOfDate,DESC1,DynamicId,[Value]) VALUES ('9-30-2017',67,'[U.G.5]',3788.89)
```

Doing it this way you've converted columns into rows.

```
    SELECT
        AsOfDate
        ,DESC1
        ,DynamicId
        ,[Value]
        ,SUM([Value]) AS [Sum]
    FROM test_table
    GROUP BY 
        AsOfDate
        ,DESC1
        ,DynamicId
        ,[Value]
```

If you have to make this data presentable it would be easiest to do it using a scripting language, however, if you need to solve this in TSQL you might consider using a pivot table.

```
    SELECT 
        AsOfDate
        ,DynamicId
        ,[63] AS [63]
        ,[64] AS [64]
        ,[65] AS [65]
        ,[66] AS [66]
        ,[67] AS [67]
    FROM
    (SELECT DynamicId, [Value], AsOfDate, DESC1 FROM test_table) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(SourceTable.[Value])
        FOR SourceTable.DESC1 IN ([63],[64],[65],[66],[67])
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks Joe!!  Happy holidays to you!!